Azure Data Mapper VS Code Extension - Filter function
I am trying to do an XSLT mapping using the new extension from Azure Logic App called Data Mapper on VS code.
I have a source xml schema that has a loop of inside (repeating structure). I need to filter this source loop with a given condition. I tried to use the "filter" function in the visual code mapper to filter the below N1Loop1 based on condition that child N101 is equal to "ST" :


I am now supposed to get the right N1Loop1 instance that stratifies my filter criteria. How do I then access sub childs from that instance to map them to the actual target schema?
The documentation is very poor on this Data Mapper Extension and can't really find ways to do what I would say is a very standard map transformation.
Thanks a lot for any support.

please share your source and destination schemas

I wanted to do so, issue is that my source schema is an X12 EDI schema with around 50 000 lines and I am not sure how I could upload this to my post. Any idea?

Can you try to use 'eq ST'?

My difficulty resides more on what should I be doing after the filtering step, how do I use the output of the filter step? As this should have filtered the input collection and provides me with one instance, I am now trying to access a specific node within that instance but not sure how to do that. Which function should I use to access a node from the filter output function?

Are you able to get the expected response from filter function?

You need to call your function refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-maps-data-transformation-visual-studio-code#call-your-map-from-a-workflow-in-your-project. Use Transform using Data Mapper XSLT action

Yes this I know once I have produced the XSLT, I was more asking about how to use the outcome of the "FILTER" function within my XSLT to further map the node from this output function to the target field. There is no select node functionoid in the Data Mapper Extension

Your design should look like this.
